# AWS S3 Permissios - Create Folder while only being able to upload certain extensions

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-policies

I'm trying to write an IAM policy to do the following:

- Allow user to access a specific bucket
- Only be able to upload a selected few types of files.. based on extensions
- **Allow to create a folder in that bucket**

I've managed to do the first two, but I'm unable to get the third requirement to work.
This is what I've tried:

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
            "s3:GetBucketLocation",
            "s3:ListAllMyBuckets"
        ],
        "Resource": "*"
    },
    {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
            "s3:ListBucket"
        ],
        "Resource": [
            "arn:aws:s3:::bucketxxx"
        ]
    },
    {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
            "s3:PutObject",
            "s3:GetObject",
            "s3:GetObjectVersion"
        ],
        "Resource": [
            "arn:aws:s3:::bucketxxx/*.mp4",
            "arn:aws:s3:::bucketxxx/*.pdf",
            "arn:aws:s3:::bucketxxx/*.jpg",
            "arn:aws:s3:::bucketxxx/*.png",
            "arn:aws:s3:::bucketxxx/*.xlsx",
            "arn:aws:s3:::bucketxxx/*.csv"
        ]
    }
]
```

}

Comment: Why do you mean by "folders"? There is no such concept in S3 as folders. AWS console only visual represents keys with slashes as "folders".

Comment: ofcourse there is! if I use the above permission to create folder it gives this error: Insufficient permission to create folder
After you or your AWS administrator have updated your permissions to allow the s3:PutObject action, choose

Comment: What is an example of the folder name? Because your policy seems to allow only, e.g., `bucketxxx/folder1/file.mp4`, not ` `bucketxxx/folder1/`.

Comment: yes that's what I cant figure out

Comment: Hi, have you managed to get this working?

Answer (score 0):

You might add `"arn:aws:s3:::bucketxxx/*/"`, to your list of resources.  As @marcin mentions, "folders" are just 0-byte objects whose name happens to end in a trailing slash.